# Can not log into alfresco community edition after power failure

Tags: alfresco

I was out of town and when I returned my server was off due to a power failure. All systems are functional but I can no longer log into Alfresco Community Edition. I have looked at several forums, but no real solutions.

Comment: Do you have some logs ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things you need to check before we can help you. These include things like:

- Is the server running?
- Can you connect to it via SSH?
- Do you have a web proxy (like Apache or Nginx) installed?
- Can you grep for that process?
- Can you hit the web proxy?
- Can you grep for the tomcat process?
- Do you see anything in the logs?
- Can you hit the Alfresco webapp on 8080?
- Can you hit the Share webapp on 8080?
- Is the database running?
- If your content store storage is on a mount point, is the volume mounted?
- Can you browse the content store directory?